# Get multiple checkbox value and pass to PHP in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have multiple checkbox below to add user access:

[image]

Each module have different ID. But now I confused how to get the checkbox value and then update it using ajax.

Example for:

- Module Location, I check Create and Edit.
- Module Department I check Only View

(Have same group ID)

I didn't get the logic how to pass it to ajax and save it to database based on Module ID and Group ID.

Source code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "loadModule.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:
    {
        groupName: $("#groupName").val()
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (jsonStr)
    {
        var len = jsonStr.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            var moduleID = jsonStr[i].moduleID;
            var moduleName = jsonStr[i].moduleName;
            var projectName = jsonStr[i].projectName;
            var groupID = jsonStr[i].groupID;
            var chkModule = jsonStr[i].chkModule;
            var chkEdit = jsonStr[i].chkEdit;

            var tr_str = "<tr id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"'>" +
            "<td>" + projectName + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + moduleName + "</td>" +
            "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"' name='chk[]' class='chk' value='CREATE'/><input type='hidden' id='groupIDInput' value='"+jsonStr[i].groupID+"'/></td>" +
            "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"' name='chk[]' class='chk' value='EDIT'/></td>" +
            "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"' name='chk[]' class='chk' value='VIEW'/></td>" +
            "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' id='"+jsonStr[i].moduleID+"' name='chk[]' class='chk' value='DELETE'/></td>" +
            "</tr>";
            $('.dataShow2').show();
            $("#tData tbody").append(tr_str);
        }
}
```

What I want:

1. Get the checkbox value using ajax
2. Pass it to PHP to save to database.

JS btnUpdate

```
$('#btnUpdate').on('click', function()
    {
        var val = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
            val[i] = $(this).val();
        });

        var chkCreateInputValue = [];            
        $('input[name^=chkProjectInput]').each(function(){
            chkCreateInputValue.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "updateGroupAccess.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:
            {
                chk: val,
                groupIDInput: $("#groupIDInput").val(),
                chkCreateInputValue: chkCreateInputValue
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (jsonStr)
            {
                $("#btnUpdate").attr({disabled: true, value: "Update"}).addClass('btn_inact').removeClass('btn_act');;
            }
        });
    });
```

and the PHP

```
if(!empty($_POST['chk']))
            {
                foreach($_POST['chkCreateInputValue'] as $chkCreateInputValue)
                {
                    if(!in_array($chkCreateInputValue, $_POST['chk'])){
                        $del = oci_parse($c1, "DELETE FROM WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSMODULES WHERE MODULEID_FK = '$chkCreateInputValue' AND GROUPID_FK = '$groupIDInput'");
                        oci_execute($del);
                    }
                }

                foreach($_POST['chk'] as $chk)
                {
                    $qChk = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSMODULES WHERE GROUPID_FK = '$groupIDInput' AND MODULEID_FK IN ('$chk')");
                    oci_execute($qChk);
                    if(oci_fetch($qChk) > 0)
                    {
                        $sql = oci_parse($c1, "UPDATE WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSMODULES SET CHKCREATE = 'Y' WHERE GROUPID_FK = '$groupIDInput' AND MODULEID_FK IN ('$chk')");
                        oci_execute($sql);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $date_added = date("d-M-Y H:i:s");

                        $sql = oci_parse($c1, "INSERT INTO WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSMODULES(MODULEID_FK, GROUPID_FK, DATEADDED, ADDEDBY) VALUES('$chk', '$groupIDInput', TO_DATE('$date_added', 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), '$getUserID')");
                        oci_execute($sql);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {

                foreach($_POST['chkCreateInputValue'] as $chkCreateInputValue)
                {
                    if(!in_array($chkCreateInputValue, $_POST['chk'])){
                        $del = oci_parse($c1, "DELETE FROM WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSMODULES WHERE GROUPID_FK = '$groupIDInput'");
                        oci_execute($del);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This problem description looks complete... Except what you've tried is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really this works fine, but the idea like this may help you:

```
<script>
var data={'CREATE':[],'EDIT':[],'VIEW':[],'EDIT':[]};
var tmp=document.getElementsByName('chk[]');
for(var i=0,j=tmp.length;i<j;i++){
    if(tmp[i].checked){
        data[tmp[i].value].push(tmp[i].id);
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url:'save.php',
    data:{'data':data},
    type:'POST',
    success:function(){
        /*Callback Function*/
    }
});
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    if(count($_POST['data']['CREATE'])){
        /* Do Something */
    }

    if(count($_POST['data']['EDIT'])){
        /* Do Something */
    }

    if(count($_POST['data']['VIEW'])){
        /* Do Something */
    }

    if(count($_POST['data']['EDIT'])){
        /* Do Something */
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How to know that the checked value is for each module on my example?

Comment: I am sorry because I've not read carefully, I am updating my code.

Comment: Ok just check it out @HiDayurieDave

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allCheckboxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox');
let data = {
  read: []
  ,write: []
  ,edit: []
  ,delete: []
}

allCheckboxs.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const self = e.target
    const className = self.className
    const id = self.dataset.id
    console.log(id)
    if(self.checked){
      data[className].push(id)
    }else{
      const index = data[className].indexOf(id);
      if (index > -1) {
          data[className].splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    console.log(data)
  })
})

// Do you AWESOME AJAX magic...
```

```html
<p>
  Rainbow Dash: 
  Read <input type='checkbox' class='read' data-id='rainbowdash'/>
  Write <input type='checkbox' class='write' data-id='rainbowdash'/>
  Edit <input type='checkbox' class='edit' data-id='rainbowdash'/>
  Delete <input type='checkbox' class='delete' data-id='rainbowdash'/>
</p>

<p>
  Pinkie Pie: 
  Read <input type='checkbox' class='read' data-id='pinkiepie'/>
  Write <input type='checkbox' class='write' data-id='pinkiepie'/>
  Edit <input type='checkbox' class='edit' data-id='pinkiepie'/>
  Delete <input type='checkbox' class='delete' data-id='pinkiepie'/>
</p>

<p>
  Flutterhsy: 
  Read <input type='checkbox' class='read' data-id='flutterhsy'/>
  Write <input type='checkbox' class='write' data-id='flutterhsy'/>
  Edit <input type='checkbox' class='edit' data-id='flutterhsy'/>
  Delete <input type='checkbox' class='delete' data-id='flutterhsy'/>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you give me the example same with my example?

Comment: But I didn't have the access to the `jsonStr` and `[i]` variable

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question, please have a look and need your help :)

Comment: First, you can just copy the JavaScript part, and it should work with your exists code base, and second I still don't know what is your `jsonStr` variable

Comment: Hi, sorry just updated again my question. Please have a look for jsonStr clarification

Comment: Hi, any advice?

Comment: Sorry mate, my company have a internet issue, so I might need to help you later on when I'm free

Comment: Sure, take your time.

Comment: Hi @HiDayurieDave , can you give me your `jsonStr`, so I can working around with your code

Comment: TBH, you can just take the JavaScript code, and replace the some of the code to fit inside your existing code?

Comment: I don't get what you mean!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137031/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-felix-fong).